# Converting a DataRow.ItemArray[x] to int

Tags: c#

```
foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)   
{
 int num = ((int)dr.ItemArray[0] / 14) * 12.5;
}
```

This is coming back as an invalid cast.  Without the cast though it's an Object being treated like an int.  How would I get this conversion to work?

Comment: Well, what is `dr.Item(0)`? What type is it? Also note that you are doing integer division that might not give you the result you expected

Comment: You can use `int.TryParse` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This is not your answer, but, to acces to data rows columns is dr[0] or dr["columnname"]

Comment: Just corrected the code...I had posted an older VB version.

Comment: Whas is the type of ItemArray[0] ?

Answer (score 1):

Rep too low to comment.

Try:

```
(int)Math.Round(((int)dr.Item(0) / 14) * 12.5)
```

You can use Math.Floor() or Math.Ceiling() if you need a particular rounding direction.

Answer (score 1):

It should be `double` not `int` thats why invalid cast error you got.

```
double num = ((int)dr.ItemArray[0] / 14) * 12.5;
```

or

```
double a = 0;
bool test = double.TryParse(dr.ItemArray[0].ToString(), out a);
if (test)
{
    int pot = (int)((a / 14) * 12.5);
}
```

Hope helps,

Comment: Same issue as above. The (int) cast is invalid.

Comment: @user1327418 Did you debug? What is the value of `dr.ItemArray[0]`?

Comment: In this case it is 81.5

Comment: @user1327418 it is also a `double` not `int`. Check updated answer please.

Comment: But really where are your data coming from? If it's from a text file your value could contain a special character that is not represented visually when you view the value in the debugger. Is dr[0].ToString().Length equals 4?

Comment: @user3532232 It is coming from DataSet. I tried with 81.5 value and code works.

Comment: berkay obviously your code is ok : ) I tried to ask @user1327418 where his data is originating from. if it was from an excel document or something else?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)   
{
  int number1 = 0;
  bool canConvert = Int32.TryParse(dr.Item(0), out number1);

  if (canConvert == true)
     int num = (Convert.ToInt32(dr.Item(0)) / 14) * 12.5;


}
```

Comment: That still presents an Object (dr.Item(0)) being used as an Int. And casts are not valid.

Comment: Why not using `number1` inside if block? And update your answer, there is no more `dr.Item` in the question.

Answer (score 0):

But what is the value of `dr[0]`?

Could you use `Convert.ToInt32(dr[0].ToString());`

Is the value a text representation of a decimal number with a nordic typing eg `5,72` you will have to make a

```
Convert.ToInt32(dr[0].ToString().Replace(",",".");
```